# Why can't I install Sass on Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, macos-sierra

I have tried installing Sass three times on Mac OS Sierra(10.12) from the terminal typing the following code:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Then it asks for my password, I enter it and nothing happens (I even waited half an hour) it does not even gives any error or any other message, then when I try to close the terminal window a message appears saying that the processing will terminate if I close the window.

I already checked on if ruby is installed on my Mac and this is the version I have:

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

What should I do?

NOTE: I'm a newbie and don't know about programming at all and this is the first time I use the terminal.

Comment: It seems odd that it would stick like that. What happens if you try with out `sudo`? Does it at least error out?

Comment: @tadman I tried it without sudo, still nothing happens and it does not give any error...

Comment: That's really odd. You may want to use something other than the system Ruby. [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) is a tool for managing that, making it easy to juggle multiple versions, plus get the current one instead of the older 2.0 version. It also doesn't require `sudo` for everything.

Answer (score 14):

I had the exact same issue but found a solution for a similar thread on Compass.

You might need to install the developer tools first by entering the following on the command line:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then try

```
sudo gem install sass
```

It worked for me and I am now running Sass 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge)

Comment: Worked for me (mac OS Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: I'm on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2. I followed @sandeep-ranjan 's answer first, which resulted in a few more lines of output from `sudo gem install sass` : 

`Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2
Fetching: ffi-1.9.21.gem (100%) `

But it didn't solve the problem. Then I followed this answer and the installation worked. Not sure if following Sandeep's answer first was necessary or not.

Answer (score 6):

Buddy,

I just now faced the same problem exactly same.

```
$ brew install ruby
```

make sure homebrew is installed on your PC then I did

```
$ sudo gem install sass
```

The installation took place

```
$ sass -v
Sass 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge)
```

Hope it helps you too..

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem installing the `Sass`.
After installing `Xcode` with

```
xcode-select --install
```

I agree the license with

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and finally run the app `Xcode` and finished installing.
After that I write `sudo gem install sass` and it works.