# An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Sass' after macOS HighSierra in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, sass, phpstorm, macos-high-sierra

After update to latest macOS High Sierra Version 10.13 my PhpStorm (version 2017.2) program cannot execute Sass Compiler

> An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Sass'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/sass" (in directory "/Users/..../"): error=2, No such file or directory

Any pointers some1 in the middle of a lot of projects

Comment: Try reinstalling Saas -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000617350-Cannot-run-program-usr-local-bin-scss-after-updating-to-High-Sierra

Comment: Can't get Sass installed: sass -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/sass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Updated ruby updated XCODE updated Gem nothing seems to work better start another thread for this issue I guess

Comment: Based on latest error -- reinstall Ruby first? Sorry, not a Mac/Ruby user so cannot help much here :( But so far it's a HighSierra related issue and not PhpStorm one.

Comment: tnx for your help and quick responses! here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261658/why-cant-i-install-sass-on-mac-os-sierra

Comment: Same here after upgrade to High Sierra: `xcode-select --install` then `sudo gem install sass` and it worked again.